# jQuery Datatables and jScrollPane header scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, datatables

I'm trying to get custom looking horizontal scrollbar for jQuery Datatables. Using some information I found so far, I came up with something like this:

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    "bFilter": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "sPaginationType": "two_button",
    "iDisplayLength": 6,                    

    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": "110%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,            

    "fnInitComplete": function() {
        var table_header,
        _this = this;
        table_header = $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css('position',
            'relative');
        $('body').find('.dataTables_scrollBody').bind('jsp-scroll-x',
            function(event, scrollPositionX, isAtLeft, isAtRight) {
                table_header.css('right', scrollPositionX);
            }).jScrollPane({
                verticalDragMinHeight: 8, 
                verticalDragMaxHeight: 8,
                horizontalDragMinWidth: 82, 
                horizontalDragMaxWidth: 82,
                autoReinitialise: true
            });
        });
```

It works fine: however, when I resize the window the table header doesn't scale down the same way that the content does (header is wider than content).  Is there any way to attach jScrollPane to jQuery Datatables to scroll header and body equally?  I mean something like:

```
$('#blabla').find('.dataTables_scrollBody').jScrollPane();
```

but for scrollBody AND scrollHead. Or is there any way for initializing scrollable Datatable without division to separate header and body?

Thanks!

Comment: how about if you reload the page when the browser resize like: 
`$(window).bind('resize',function(){
     window.location.href = window.location.href;
});`

Comment: i doesn't work, even when page is reloaded. You see, the problem is that I can skip this tricky part by making not Datatable but outer container scrollable. That one works how it's suppose to but again, there's one thing, one little thing called pagination :) Paginator scrolls with entire container since it's inside it and it looks really silly when You scroll right and happen to have "previous" button hidden and "next" on the center of Your screen. I'm not saying it's not the way to go but I have no clue how to fix pagination position to stay in place...